# How to choose the number of latent dimensions in VAE?

Tags: image-processing, autoencoders, variational

I have trained a VAE that can generate photos of human faces.

I have isolated the dimension that correlates most to smiling and now I only want the VAE to generate smiling faces.

May I know is it a usual practice to adjust the `latent_dim` value in order to optimize the attributes (e.g. naturalness etc.) of the generated samples?

I suppose an extremely low `latent_dim` will cause excessive information compression.

How about a high `latent_dim`? Is it always better to use a higher number of `latent_dim`?

Or is such a choice of `latent_dim` a hyperparameter optimization problem that depends on the problem?

p.s. I'm trying to master VAE so GANs is out of context for now.